# How to add a formula as a prefix/suffix to multiple text cells (in their original cells)

Tags: excel, concatenation

I am needing to add a formula as a prefix to a set of cell values, in the same cells they were originally in.

Example

The formula that I want to insert is =$B$2

and I have a list of values in A1 to A5:

Hello
HelloWorld
Hello World
Goodbye
Bye

The end result in A1 - A5 would be, if B2 was "hi ",

hi Hello
hi HelloWorld
hi Hello World
hi Goodbye
hi Bye

I don't want to be left with a random list of cells elsewhere that hold the original values for A1-A5 which makes it tricky because I'm trying to fit text format and a formula format into the same cell on a large scale.

Any help is appreciated because I can't seem to find solutions online currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to change and run this short macro:

```
Sub Formulaizer()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)

    For Each r In Selection
        r.Formula = "=$B$2 & " & DQ & r.Text & DQ
     Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to keep away from VBA but it worked

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, you are better off putting in separate formulae in A1 to A5 and one value in B2 (which you can modify). For your example:

A1 should have `=concatenate($B$2," Hello")`

A2 should have `=concatenate($B$2," HelloWorld")`

A3 should have `=concatenate($B$2," Hello World")`

A4 should have `=concatenate($B$2," Goodbye")`

A5 should have `=concatenate($B$2," Bye")`

B2 should have `hi`

This is because you state that you want them to be in original cells A1 to A5.

Usually, Excel works as [Data in cell/column/row/sheet] x [Formula in another cell/column/row/sheet] --> Results in cell/column/row/sheet where the formula was entered.

In your case, since you want your results to be in A1 to A5 only, your data is embedded in the formulae in A1 to A5 as stated above.

If your A1 to A5 is always data that you enter manually, you can keep your B2 in place and maybe have the formula in C1 to C5[?] which will look something like this: C1 =concatenate(A1,$B$2)... [and so on]
[Just a suggestion]

Comment: Hey M.L.

A1-A5 (which in reality is more like A1 - A500 per sheet), already exists. 

The issue for me is that I am updating a lot of spreadsheets that have all the information inputted, and all that needs to happen is a variable (B2) needs to be inputted in front of every cell on each spreadsheet, and it preferably doesn't have references to lots of other cells.

The solution would be each cell referencing the variable B2, then itself, however then you get an infinite loop and it wouldn't work

Comment: In that case, I'd do it in another column (column C as mentioned in the above solution). If you don't have a free column (C), then add a column, use the formula(e) in this added column and then paste is back as values in column A (1-500) and delete the column with the formulae, which brings the sheet back to the same shape as before. (If I don't have room on the sheet, then I follow the addition and deletion of column method, and it works for even a million rows)

Comment: I think that leaves me with two formula within the concatenate, so I can either then paste it back into the cell as a text format which loses the =$B$2 variable, or paste it back into the original cells as a formula and then that returns #ref because it can't reference itself. Or I would have to manually write every concatenate in column C, which negates the shortcut? The concatenate works fine when I can leave the 3rd column existing, however this will end up being used by lots of people who aren't very competent with Excel so I'd like to keep extra cell usage to a minimum.